# Skipping some license tests in Maven

Tags: maven, licensing

I want to skip some license tests but in vain.

I tried several things such as `-Dlicense.skip=true` or `-Dlicensing` or
`-Drat.numUnapprovedLicenses=100`.

Still, it didn't work.
How can I skip this process?

Comment: "mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dlicense.skip=true" worked for me.  Are there any log error for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i skip the license check when running the maven install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281794/how-do-i-skip-the-license-check-when-running-the-maven-install)

Answer (score 49):

I would suggest to read the [documentation which brings up the following](http://creadur.apache.org/rat/apache-rat-plugin/check-mojo.html#ignoreErrors):

```
mvn -Drat.ignoreErrors=true package
```

What is also possible to [skip it completely via](http://creadur.apache.org/rat/apache-rat-plugin/check-mojo.html#skip):

```
mvn -Drat.skip=true package
```

Comment: Hm, I did like this "mvn clean -e -DskipTests -Dcheckstyle.skip=true -Drat.ignoreErrors=true install", then It says "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.7:check (default) on project giraph: Too many unapproved licenses: 80 -> [Help 1]"
Is there anything I did wrong?

Answer (score 13):

Run the build with this parameter
-Drat.numUnapprovedLicenses=100

Answer (score 3):

I ran into similar issues and skipped license check by only `-Dlicense.skip`.

Answer (score 0):

In pom file change version as below apache-rat-plugin
                0.12