# How can I disable Apache RAT (Release Audit Tool) in Maven

Tags: maven, archiva

I have checked out Apache Archiva Redback and the compile is failing when I do `mvn install` because Apache RAT is failing and I haven't changed anything yet.

Comment: http://creadur.apache.org/rat/apache-rat-plugin/check-mojo.html#skip

Comment: You should fix the problems instead of skipping it...

Comment: @khmarbaise Please feel free but I don't have time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping some license tests in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181154/skipping-some-license-tests-in-maven)

Answer (score 43):

You can disable RAT by adding `-Drat.skip=true` to your maven command line.

Comment: Does this only apply to maven, or would it work on, say, my garage?

Answer (score 2):

You can config it in your pom file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>

    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```