# How do i skip the license check when running the maven install?

Tags: maven, license-maven-plugin

I ran a `mvn clean install` on a big Java project that I work on, but it kept failing due to some files not having the proper license headers. Well, thats not my concern right now, how do I skip that? the actual error i am seeing is,

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:license-maven-plugin:1.14:add-third-party (default) on project test-project: There are some dependencies with no license, please fill the file /Users/test-project/src/license/THIRD-PARTY.properties
```

I also tried this maven command, but it didn't work

```
mvn clean install -Dlicense.skip=true
```

Comment: Which goal of the license plugin is run? Is it defined in your own pom or in some parent pom? In the first case, you can delete it from the pom, in the second case, you can probably set a "skip" parameter to true.

Comment: This goal is defined in the parent pom, I thought it would be nice if i can disable the check in the maven command itself, instead of changing in parent pom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try skipping AddThirdParty mojo with `-Dlicense.skipAddThirdParty=true`.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it worked with just `-Dlicense.skip`, without `=true`.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mycila</groupId>
  <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this helpful

```
$ mvn license:help -Ddetail | fgrep skip
```

which gave me

```
-Dlicense.skipDownloadLicenses
```

you don't need to add `=true` because just defining it is enough.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
-Dlicense.skipCheckLicense
```